# What is that? chip identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

What is that? No HD-SDI signal.
Black magic camera motherboard
[image]

Comment: It might be a circuit produced on purpose for the product... and although it might be a SoC containing also a microcontroller, it looks more like some analog system dealing with high-frequency signals (as Majenko noted, there is something looking like a impedance matching circuit on the right side). What is the BNC connector for, an antenna? A video input/output?

Comment: -What is the BNC connector for, an antenna? A video input/output? It's a video HD SDI output

Answer (score 2):

It might be a custom chip built by Gennum/Semtech. The numers on the chip seem to correspond to those of HD-SDI cable drivers they make (e.g. the GS1678), in particular *0002E3* should be batch number 0002 (this very low batch number and the absence of an identifiable part name make me think of a custom chip), *E3* on their packages is meaning RoHS compatible, and *1352* should mean that it has been manufactured on week 52 (end of December) of 2013.

The chip looks very similar to their [GS1678 HD-SDI](http://www.semtech.com/broadcast-video/cable-drivers/gs1678/) cable driver it has the same QFN16 package, and the pins seem to be used for similar/identical purposes:

[image: GS1678 pinout, taken from official datasheet]

Image from [datasheet](https://downloads.semtech.com/extranet/document/54169)

In particular, you can notice that pins 9 (VCC) and 6 (DISABLE*) are connected together, which perfectly makes sense, and RSET (pin 4) is connected as required to a resistor (possibly going to VCC through the via). The top four pins are not connected (except maybe pin 16? not sure from the image where the track nearby is going), the DDI pins (1/2) have two ceramic capacitors nearby as expected per datasheet, and the output signal (going to the BNC through the matching network) seems to come out from SDO (pin 12) as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that looks like an impedance matching circuit coming from the right of it, going to the BNC connector, so my guess is it's some kind of RF (or similar) transceiver chip maybe.

Answer (score 0):

For HD-SDI? It's probably the cable driver and output filter.  Hard to see the numbers in that pic.